# Why can't I update my image in AKS? Error: Docker Registry service connection details not specified

Tags: azure-aks

[image][image]I am new to the AKS world and I am getting stuck I get the error message " ##[error]Docker Registry service connection details not specified". As soon as I start a new release this error message appears. I've changed my permissions in the meantime. I entered my subscription wherever I had to. I also defined the CLIENT_ID, ACR_ID and created a ROLE assignment. After 13 failed releases, I am asking you now.

Comment: It seems you need to create a [docker registry connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-docreg) in the pipeline.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have already saved my personal Docker registry in the Service Connection. Have now uploaded a picture of the config. Unfortunately, the bug is still there.

Comment: Do you try to check the docker registry credential if it can pull the image?

Comment: I did that now and there was the mistake. Thank you for your help

Comment: Do you mean you made the mistake so that the credential is not right?

Comment: No I forgot the secrets subscription for the update image in AKS Deployment

Comment: OK, so you solve the problem now?

Comment: Yes. Thx again :)

Comment: Well, if you do not mind, I will add the answer and can you accept it?

Comment: yes pls add the answer

Comment: I think you misunderstand what I mean. I mean you can accept my answer, not vote up it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the error you got, it happened because you do not set the service connection for the Docker registry. So you can follow the steps in [Docker Registry Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-docreg) to create the service connection.